# Heroku NodeJS + CouchBase Custom Buildpack

Tags: heroku, couchbase, buildpack

I'm trying to put together a custom buildpack with NodeJS and the CouchBase module/libraries

I've gotten as far as using Vulcan to build libcouchbase and libvbucket and getting the buildpack to retrieve and unpack the tgz files for both.

Everything looks ok there, but I receive errors when npm tries to install the couchbase module:

I get a bunch of errors, but this line:

"../src/couchbase_impl.h:52:36: warning: libcouchbase/couchbase.h: No such file or directory"

leads me to think that it can't find the libcouchbase libraries (which is possible since they aren't in the usual place).

I've tried to add the correct path using CPPFLAGS="-I/app/vendor/couchbase/include/libcouchbase" in both the Config Vars and just exporting that as part of the compile phase, but still no luck.

Here is the gist with the Heroku deploy output and the compile/release buildpack files:
https://gist.github.com/ahamidi/5620503

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ali

**[Update 1]**

I've made some progress and I can now get the slug to compile when deploying to Heroku.

The key was figuring out the ENV Variables that CouchNode looks for when adding custom directories to include.

In this case, the Env Variables were EXTRA_CPPFLAGS and EXTRA_LDFLAGS.

So I updated the compile file to include the following:

```
export EXTRA_CPPFLAGS="-I$BUILD_DIR/vendor/couchbase/include" 
export EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-L$BUILD_DIR/vendor/couchbase/lib -Wl,-rpath,$BUILD_DIR/vendor/couchbase/lib"
```

The slug compiles and the app is deployed, but I now get a different error in the logs:

```
Error: libcouchbase.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So it looks like Node can't see the libcouchbase libraries directory.

Comment: Since libcouchbase 2.0 you don't need external libvbucket, it has been bundled into libcouchbase and links statically

Comment: Your script is using some custom tarballs, why not use specific version from official site (can be found at http://couchbase.com/develop/c)?

Comment: I was under the impression that the "preferred" approach was to build the binaries using the target environments (in this case actually building on a Heroku Dyno).

Comment: @avsej Ah ok, cool thanks. I'll remove libvbucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is curious or experiencing a similar issue, here's what worked for me.

In order to get the couchbase npm module to install I had to tell it where to find the libcouchbase libraries (in compile file):

```
export EXTRA_CPPFLAGS="-I$BUILD_DIR/vendor/couchbase/include" 
export EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-L$BUILD_DIR/vendor/couchbase/lib -Wl,-rpath,$BUILD_DIR/vendor/couchbase/lib"
```

Then in order to *require* couchbase in my app I had to set the following Env Variable:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/app/vendor/couchbase/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

With the command:

```
heroku config:add LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/app/vendor/couchbase/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `CPPFLAGS="-I/app/vendor/couchbase/include" LDFLAGS="-L/app/vendor/couchbase/include -lcouchbase"`

Comment: I tried setting the Env Variables as you mentioned, but I still get the same error.

I'm not sure if it helps but the path in which I am unpacking the tarball is /app/vendor/couchbase

Additionally, the couchbase header files are not actually listing in the /app/vendor/couchbase/include directory. That directory has a sub-folder named "libcouchbase" which houses the actual files.

Answer (score 0):

from your script it seems like you just unpacking libcouchbase without any further work. you should also build it and install. typical magic spell for node.js client will be `./configure --disable-plugins --disable-examples && make && sudo make install`. I'm not sure if `sudo` part needed on heroku, probably just `make install`

Comment: I've already built libcouchbase using Vulcan, so the package includes the binaries and built libraries