# Heroku-Addon for couchbase

Tags: database, heroku, couchbase

Is there an add-on available on heroku for [couchbase](https://www.couchbase.com/). I searched in the [addons sections](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) but wasnt able to find it. 
If not, is there any way to deploy an app on heroku that uses couchbase.

PS: I want deploy on heroku specifically because its free (it doesnt even require you to register a credit card).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any official addon that is recent, but there are some older posts that describe someone trying the same thing.

- [Couchbase on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266797/couchbase-on-heroku#27823432)
- [Couchbase customer buildpack or heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674168/heroku-nodejs-couchbase-custom-buildpack)

Kurobase.com had a solution too but that seems dead.